# How do you install Openstack?

Tags: server, cloud, openstack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has anyone test-driven and/or written a howto for OpenStack cloud?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78314/has-anyone-test-driven-and-or-written-a-howto-for-openstack-cloud)

The announcement was made that Ubuntu will now package openstack by default, at the install window, do we install openstack like you would install ubuntu cloud? is it replacing ubuntu cloud? I've yet to see any official documentation talk about this release?

The following instructions are provided by openstack, but do fail at keystone installation: http://www.hastexo.com/resources/docs/installing-openstack-essex-20121-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin

for the moment there's an [unofficial documentation](https://github.com/EmilienM/doc-openstack) writen by Emilien Macchi, being contributed to the official opnestack documentation.