# does ubuntu 13.04 desktop (32 bit) already have open stack bundled in?

Tags: 32-bit

From the the literature, it seems that ONLY Ubuntu 13.04 server (64-bit) has Open Stack bundled in, and not Ubuntu 13.04 desktop (32-bit). Is this true?

Also it seems that there is NO Ubuntu 13.04 server (32-bit) codes available for download. Is this true? As such, is there, by any chance, that I could install and run Open Stack on Ubuntu (32-bit) desktop, if it has not already been bundled in?

Please provide me with instructions or pointers to instructions, whih explain how I could run Open Stack on top of Ubuntu 13.04 (32-bit) desktop.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu desktop and server editions are not separate operating systems.  Instead, they are just, for your convenience, separate installers, which each install a different subset of Ubuntu's software packages.

It is possible to install all Ubuntu server software on an installation that was originally installed with the desktop installer, and vice versa, using the package installation tools built into Ubuntu.

OpenStack is not one software package but a range of software and isn't the easiest to get started with.  Normally, you'd probably be running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS if you are running a server and installation will be via the [CloudArchive](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive).  If you're running 13.04, then you can install the included version of the OpenStack tools (grizzly) with that release.

The actual installation instructions for OpenStack are [quite complicated](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure), suffice to say that question has been [asked here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144531/how-do-i-install-openstack).