# Deploying Openstack on top of Juju+MAAS setup

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas, cloud, openstack

We've set up MAAS with 3 physical nodes. One is the controller node which is configured with a public IP visible from the outside world. The other 2 are on a private VLAN along with the cluster node. MAAS is managing DHCP. And we've installed juju on the cluster node. Now we want to deploy openstack on this setup. We followed the steps given in [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144531/how-do-i-install-openstack) and chose a `Multi-Install` and `eth0` interface( where private IPs are configed and MAAS is handling DHCP). We came to a point where we see this prompt-

[image]

We are confused what to do here. If we allow the installer to proceed and create another DHCP, what does the MAAS DHCP do then . What will be its role? And the fact that the prompt warns us of collision between servers confuses us further.

Can someone guide us in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to make sure you are using the latest installer bits to make use of installing Openstack on top of an existing MAAS:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

During the installation you will have the opportunity to choose a **Multi** installation with an existing MAAS. It will prompt you for your MAAS server ip along with the apikey of your MAAS admin user.

Once this is set it'll bootstrap juju onto your existing MAAS deployment and provide you with the ability to manually place your Openstack services or automatically apply services to your existing machines with sensible defaults for quickly getting you up and running with Openstack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we are now hitting this error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key".
Key (username)=(root) already exists.` Is it trying to create a new MAAS superuser?

Comment: Also it dint prompt IP of the existing MAAS. And it modified our environment.yaml file so much that `juju stat` itself fails like "ERROR cannot find network interface "lxcbr0": net: no such interface"

Comment: Make sure you're using version 0.21 of the installer. As the install option 'Multi with existing MAAS' should be an option

Comment: `cloud-install` has only the following options `cloud-install [-ciusha:r:]` How to check the version of the installer? I got the installer via `sudo apt-get install cloud-installer`

Comment: If you follow the install directions from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack that will get you the required installer. You can also do a `dpkg -l` to see what version you have

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have any dhcp server on eth0, either by disabling the dhcp, or configuring in an isolated network environment before you pick an interface to deploy maas on with dhcp enabled