# Unable to login into OpenStack Horizon using Icehouse

Tags: openstack

I am very new to the open stack and After a hard time's effort, I successfully installed OpenStack Icehouse on ubuntu vm (for some reasons installation was not finishing up on ubuntu host). I downloaded the source code from the link below

> `git clone http://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git -b stable/icehouse`

and ran the

`./stack.sh`

after a successful install (entered few passwords), I got the brief summary of Users, links and Passwords where it says "Horizon is running on this IP" etc. However when I open the openstack Dashboard, it doesn't authenticate with demo or admin user.

Just an FYI I searched most of the forms, however still can not figure it out. I remember few forms told if the **keystone** process is running and **yes** that is running as well. Also when I goto the **Keystone -server IP** I got the following error.

[image]

I am really new to open-stack and had always trouble installing it, also don't want to give up either like that. if someone can help, will be appreciated. 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for your current problem with devstack but invite you to try out our OpenStack Installer:

http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Single install mode is useful for running a test OpenStack cloud on a laptop or single machine. Multi makes use of MAAS and Landscape Autopilot will set you up using a reference architecture for OpenStack along with providing Landscape with 10 bare metal and 10 virtual seats for free. This license is suitable for a private cloud and several compute nodes.