# OpenStack on Ubuntu installation error

Tags: openstack

I was following to install openstack on ubuntu
[How do I install OpenStack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144531/how-do-i-install-openstack)

But I am getting the repository not found error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cloud-installer/testing/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cloud installer/testing/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I tried to access these repositories manually but not getting anywhere

It seems like that these packages are moved or deleted from the website

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the repository for Ubuntu 12.04 (`precise`). This is no longer supported. Change your repository to point to Ubuntu 14.04 (`trusty`) or Ubuntu 14.10 (`utopic`).