# Unable to deploy Instance after finishing installation OpenStack on single node

Tags: juju, openstack

I finished the installation of OpenStack on a Single server like instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144531/how-do-i-install-openstack), but I get an error while launching an instance.

```
Failed to launch instance "test1": Please try again later [Error: No valid host was found. ].
```

Details:

```
Fault

Message
No valid host was found.
Code
500
Details
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/conductor/manager.py", line 616, in build_instances request_spec, filter_properties) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/client/__init__.py", line 49, in select_destinations context, request_spec, filter_properties) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/client/__init__.py", line 35, in __run_method return getattr(self.instance, __name)(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/client/query.py", line 34, in select_destinations context, request_spec, filter_properties) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/rpcapi.py", line 108, in select_destinations request_spec=request_spec, filter_properties=filter_properties) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/messaging/rpc/client.py", line 152, in call retry=self.retry) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/messaging/transport.py", line 90, in _send timeout=timeout, retry=retry) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 408, in send retry=retry) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 399, in _send raise result
Created
May 7, 2015, 4:07 p.m.
```

I am really new with this so I am just getting my bearings. How can I debug a bit further what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by connecting to the Computing Module and:

Adding the following line at /etc/nova/nova.conf:

```
libvirt_type=qemu
```

And performing a restart of the Nova VM.

HTH