# openstack single-server install fails at juju bootstrap stage

Tags: juju, openstack

I am following the single-server install described at

[How do I install OpenStack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144531/how-do-i-install-openstack)

but the install fails during the 'boostrapping juju' stage.

The resulting commands.log file is pasted at

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11011586/

I am installing on a Virtual machine.
The commands I am running are

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cloud-installer/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openstack
sudo openstack-install
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.0.4.1

```
3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help getting around this error would be much appreciated, tx

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I didn't think the ubuntu openstack single-installer was supposed to be used in a hw vm.   It already builds everything inside of a single LXC container (nesting other servers inside that lxc container)

But also check the "issues" logged in github or the "bugs" logged in launchpad for the single-installer such as the one described in this thread.

https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/470