# i want to setup openstack please help

Tags: backup, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I am looking at starting a small backup company in my country and i was hoping to use openstack to build my private cloud... and also the main backup software I use loves Swift. The basic install [(link)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) helps a little, but i am looking for a more in depth guide/tutorial

Where can i find a proper guide on what hardware is best for the servers.. number of servers.. and if its going to be easy to add storage nodes afterwards .. like 3 45 drive units filled with drives.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install OpenStack?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144531/how-do-i-install-openstack)

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenStack Operations Guide](http://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ops/content/index.html) is pretty thorough. Chapter 11 covers [Maintenance, Failures, and Debugging](http://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ops/content/maintenance.html#hardware) and has information on adding/replacing different types of nodes. You can also search that guide from the top left for any other topics that interest you.