# Running an OpenStack test environment at home

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have a HP DL360 G5 at home and it has a ESXi 6.0 installed on it.

I want to know more abount Ubuntu Openstack, but there is too much information and it is are confusing. What do I need to get Ubuntu OpenStack running in my existing environment? Do I need MAAS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install OpenStack?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144531/how-do-i-install-openstack)

Comment: Lucio, I don't wanna know how to, I need to know what do I need to.

Comment: With just scrolling a little bit you will see a big **Requirements** section there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go to the source on this one:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

Their hardware requirements are high, not in terms of resources, but in terms of the amount of hardware needed:

> Installing Ubuntu OpenStack requires at least seven machines with two >disks, two of which have two network interfaces (NICs). Install Ubuntu >Server on one of the machines with two interfaces.

To meet these requirements, you can use the HP DL360 and some older machines you might have laying around or you can use VMs as noted in http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_basic_environment.html#basics-prerequisites

You can use many tools to create VMs, but as you would wind up with nested virtualization, Virtualbox is not an option.