# Good scalability of Cluster /Cloud?

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack

Good afternoon,

I am interested to create an cloud using Ubuntu. For this I want to use Openstack. But also I see that that I can install also Juju and Maas. All of them work together very well and also have their role in cloud.

My question is: what is the order in which must be installed (1. Ubuntu Server, 2. Juju 3. Maas, 4. OpenStack)?
For my necessity is necessary all of them?
In this configuration for OpenStack can be split the instalation as default? (Network, ...)

I must specify that the cluster will be dedicate only to: CAD, CAM, and CAE. On the cluster/cloud will never been installed site.

Thanks to all comunity for advice and support. 
I waiting your sugestion/recomandation with interest.

Keep in touch.

Answer (score 1):

This question will lead you down the right path:

- [How do I install OpenStack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144531/how-do-i-install-openstack)

I'll give you a high level overview of what happens when you do this so it's clear to you how the big pieces move. If you follow the link above, what we call "The OpenStack Installer" does everything I'm about to tell you in a nice, more automated way. It lets you pick how you want your networking, and a bunch of other questions that will fit exactly how you want to deploy your cloud. Here's an overview of what's happening:

- MAAS: Metal as a Service, think of this as an API for all your hardware, if you "want a machine with X cores and X amount of disks and this kind of networking" then you ask MAAS. MAAS registers all your hardware in it's database (you do this by enlisting them into MAAS), and then it kind of just sits there waiting for you. When you ask MAAS for a machine it gets you a machine, you don't need to install Ubuntu Server by hand, it will automatically keep images up to date and fresh for you. It's basically an Ubuntu-serving machine; it of course does more than that, but for now, consider it your broker for hardware.
- Juju: Juju's job is to create what you tell it to model. You say "I want a cloud that looks like this." Number of nodes, which services to put on it, etc. It takes your modelled deployment and then tells MAAS, "go get me these machines so I can make this happen." MAAS then goes and turns on all the machines standing by, installs the OS, and puts whatever you told it to on each machine ... in this case, you are telling it .... give me OpenStack.
- OpenStack is your cloud. Juju will take all of the OpenStack charms and execute that code on each of the nodes MAAS has provisioned. Swift, Nova, etc. These make up the basic components of a cloud, compute, networking, storage, identity, and then all the other things you might want.

Ok. Now here's where it gets like Inception (the movie). Juju's job is to model and orchestrate services. It did so and gave you a cloud, so now you have a cluster but it's empty. So what happens next is you go into your openstack dashboard, and then you can use Juju to deploy all the things you want running on your cloud. Juju doesn't just drive your cloud itself, it also puts what you want on top of your cloud.

At this point, unless you're adding more hardware to your cluster, you can just let the MAAS server sit there and let OpenStack manage your virtual machines and containers for all the CAD, CAM, and CAE software. You can do this by hand, or of course, write Juju charms for all the software that you want to put on your cloud.

The idea (and reason) these tools exist is that while saving you a bunch of time on the initial installation is a really great bonus, it's only a one-time savings, when you're setting up the cloud. By automating the modelling of the CAD, CAM, and CAE software and those workloads *after* you've done the installation, that's saving time over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Note, particularly in the CAD/CAM/CAE software world, you MIGHT consider using pure MAAS and JUJU vs. adding OpenStack to the mix.  OpenStack is great if you want to partition your hardware into smaller pieces (e.g. turn 3 monster servers into 30 smaller dedicated servers) OR if you need isolation on the same hardware.  This would depend entirely on your environment, number and size of servers, and software requirements.

To your specific question, there are roughly two options I see:

1. Install MAAS
2. Install JuJu
3. Install OpenStack using JuJu
4. Install CAD/etc. using JuJu onto OpenStack

OR

1. Install MAAS
2. Install JuJu
3. Install CAD/etc. using JuJu via MAAS