# Playing with Ubuntu Cloud on different machines without vlan

Tags: juju, maas, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I would like to try Ubuntu Cloud but unfortunately I don't have 3-5 bare-metal servers or a machine powerful enough to handle everything (via [virtual machines](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud)).
My idea was to rent 5 cheap servers (Hetzner, Online.net, Kimsufi etc) and give it a shot. But none of these providers offer a native vlan.
Will MAAS be unusable in this case? If yes, I suppose that also Autopilot will be unusable?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that will work. On IRC you mentioned you wanted to evaluate OpenStack and the easiest way to do that is to use the single node installer:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cloud-installer/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openstack
sudo openstack-install
```

References:

- [How do I install OpenStack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144531/how-do-i-install-openstack)
- http://openstack.astokes.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linux Containers. They're incredibly lightweight. If I can run 50 of them on an old Pentium 4 I'm sure you can play around with them.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html

http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/lxd

Comment: Currently my PC is an i7 with 8GB RAM. Will it be enough to deploy and test OpenStack "on top" of vSphere, as specified in the installation tutorial? I've read that the minimal specs is Xeon and 12GB RAM, but I might be wrong?

Comment: LXC is amazing, but on its own can't host some parts of OpenStack (in particular the tricky networking bits). We think a simple OpenStack on pure LXC 2.0 will be possible, will let you know once we get to LXC 2.0 :)

Comment: I must admit that networking with the current LXC is a bit... painful.