# How do I know if OpenStack is installed on my device or not?

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas, openstack

Following this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144531/how-do-i-install-openstack) to install OpenStack, now that I've added the repository ans I got the first interface of selecting Multi, Single or Open Stack Autopilot mode. I selected Single and then enter the password. Right after the password interface the command is terminated and it ends from there.

 How do I know if the installation is completed or not?

 Also how can I reach to the dashboard as mentioned in the link above. Yet so far there are no errors occurred.