# A step by step Openstack installation on Ubuntu tutorial

Tags: software-installation, juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I am an IT Student doing a cloud related project and self learning about cloud technology.

I am planning to build a private Cloud for my project, I have been searching for the openstack installation guidance but the problem is there are several methods available, I am so confused so please kindly post a step by step openstack installation in Ubuntu. Thank you.

Comment: btw - have you tried this http://askubuntu.com/questions/144531/how-do-i-install-openstack

Answer (score 7):

Try this. I have used the "next" PPA of conjure-up because it has a lot of fixes, but it also uses Juju 2.0 beta which is a beta :) Your call on whether you do that or use stock conjure-up from the stable archives. Note that the main archive will be updated to get the new conjure-up anyway, once Juju 2.0 is released.

If you are going to build your cloud on a single host with LXD containers, then you probably want to setup LXD to use ZFS:

```
sudo apt install zfs
sudo lxd init
```

Choose 'zfs' and either feed it a dedicated fast disk (like a spare SSD on /dev/sdc) or ask it to create a local loopback mount. I would give it at least 60G or 120G disk for a local container filesystem in ZFS.

You can test your LXD with:

```
lxc launch ubuntu:
lxc list
```

If that all works you will see an Ubuntu container firing up. The first one has to download an Ubuntu container image, after that it is very fast.

To get the conjure-up tool and juju 2.0:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conjure/next
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/devel
sudo apt update
sudo apt install juju-2.0 conjure-up
```

Now you can just go ahead:

```
conjure-up openstack
```

Once Juju 2.0 is released in Xenial you could drop the add-apt-repository lines.

Comment: Had to remove `--upload-tools` parameter from the bootstrap command. But then it gives `ERROR: Unknown cloud "baboon", please try "juju update-clouds"`, so doesn't create a local cloud. I'm doing it inside an LXD container, maybe I'll try on the bare-metal (`lxc launch ubuntu:` gives ` Permission denied - Failed to mount proc onto /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/proc`anyways, so I probably shouldn't do all complex at once).