# Installation procedure of MAAS and JUJU to deploy Openstack

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack, cloud

Could you please help me out in deploying the OpenStack on MAAS using Juju. The procedures in this forum wasn't that helpful but. Could someone please post the exact procedure to get the OpenStack up and running using correct configs through Juju.

This didn't help 
[How do I deploy an OpenStack cloud with Juju?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78314/how-do-i-deploy-an-openstack-cloud-with-juju)

Answer (score 1):

First of all install MAAS and configure juju on it correctly. If you are testing the installation, I would recommend you to use Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS installation with MAAS and install juju afterwards.

Use a Virtual Machine Manager such as Oracle VirtualBox and register the nodes in the MaaS cluster. Then you can use juju in it.

Then install openstack. 
Following link is a great tutorial for that. There are number of threads and tutorials if you want to get help in the installation steps. Hope it helps.

http://marcoceppi.com/2012/05/juju-maas-virtualbox/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Configuring juju is a problem. I am into so many issues due to lack of documentation on deploying services of openstack using juju. So i don't want to test using Oracle VBox. I have the metals, juju-core is installed. Now,downloading the required openstack services chrams such that openstack environment is created as in trystack, am not able to achieve. Please direct me in that direction.